# Standardize color scale across maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to create home range maps overtop of vegetation data. My vegetation data is continuous and between 2,000 and 7,500. I want to have one standardized color scale for all of my maps. I am trying to create my own color gradient. When I try to add my colorscale into my map, I get this error "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 27 needed but only 11 provided." I am not sure how to properly categorize my continuous values.

```
colorscale<- c("2000-2500"="yellow","2501-3000"="yellow1","3001-3500"="yellow2","3501-4000"="yellow3","4001-4500"="yellow4","4501-5000"="green","5001-5500"="green1","5501-6000"="green2","6001-6500"="green3","6501-7000"="green4", "7001-7500"="forestgreen")

abplot08<- ggplot() + geom_sf(data=abundant08_poly, aes(fill=EVI))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= colorscale)+
  geom_sf(data=wet08_sf, aes(color = Group),size=2, fill=NA)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","hotpink","green","blue","turquoise"))+
  ggtitle("Abundant Season Home Ranges 2008");abplot08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create color bins using `scale_*_steps` functions for ggplot. One way would be to create two vectors for the `colors` and  `breaks` arguments and supply them for each plot. I used some dummy data to show this. If you don't want categorical bins, you can use `scale_fill_gradientn` instead.

```
nc <- read_sf(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"))
rng <- 2000:7500
nc$randat <- rng[sample.int(length(rng), nrow(nc))]

colors <- c("yellow","yellow1","yellow2","yellow3","yellow4","green","green1","green2","green3","green4", "forestgreen")
breaks <- seq(2000, 7000, by = 500)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=nc, aes(fill=randat)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = colors, breaks=breaks)
```

[image]

**Edit** If you want a more aesthetically pleasing (traditional) color scale, you need to manually bin your data. The `cut` function will create the labels based on the break values that you set. Then you can use that as the fill variable.

```
# create breaks
breaks <- seq(2000, 7500, by = 500)

labs <- seq(2001, 7001, by = 500)
labs[1] <- labs[1] - 1
# create labels to use as fill variable
labs <- paste(labs, 'to', breaks[2:length(breaks)])

# applies labels to bins based on breaks
nc['cat'] <- cut(nc$randat, breaks=breaks, labels = labs)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=nc, aes(fill=cat)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors)
```

[image]